# Why does rsnapshot's sync/sync_first command backup ALL my files everytime?

Tags: linux, backup, rsnapshot

I'm trying to get rsnapshot working for remote backups (via ssh). I have a working configuration and I can perform all my backups.

In my conf I have enabled `sync_first=1`. As I understand it, this means that I have to always first run the `rsnapshot sync` command to actually go and grab the backup files first, then run the `rsnapshot hourly` command to simply symlink and rotate the backups.

Now the problem. I'm not sure if this is by design, but I am noticing that every time I run `rsnapshot sync`, **every** file on my remote machine it being backed again regardless of whether it has changed since the last backup. This means the `rsnapshot sync` command takes > 1hr.

Is this the designed behaviour?

Should I be running `sync` every hour before running `hourly/daily/weekly`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be running `sync` first. `sync` synchronizes to the `.sync` directory. `hourly` then rotates away `.sync` to `hourly.0`. The nice thing is that you can run `rsnapshot sync` again, after an interrupted `rsnapshot sync`, and it will continue where it left off.

I have this in my crontab:

```
# make backups every 2 hours - and skip hourly backups at night
0 0,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /opt/bin/rsnapshot sync && /opt/bin/rsnapshot hourly

# rotate a daily every night at 5
0 5 * * * /opt/bin/rsnapshot daily
```

Do note that, in the above crontab, if `rsnapshot sync` produced warnings, but could still finish the backup, it will return with an error code of 2. That means that `rsnapshot hourly` will not run. If this happens every time, then you don't have any hourlies, nor dailies - just the `.sync` directory.

Comment: How is your BACKUP INTERVALS configuration in /etc/snapshot.conf ?

Comment: I seem to have no problem here, but I use only daily backups: http://serverfault.com/questions/788992/configuring-rsnapshot-to-only-daily-backups-with-sync-first

Comment: @rubo77 You can find the full configuration in this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/frankkusters/5bb28c4d1ce4aadd0ae1).

Comment: Should I run sync before smallest interval or before all and why?

Comment: @Mindau Before the smallest interval, because the smallest interval rotates the `.sync` directory to `<smallestinterval>.0`.

Comment: @FrankKusters and  what rotates to bigger interval?

Comment: @Mindau I advise you to read the [How it works](http://rsnapshot.org/rsnapshot/docs/docbook/rest.html#how-it-works) section of rsnapshot's documentation. It's only one screenful and not very technical.